# Preferred way to query a database multiple times?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

When using JDBC in Java, the generally accepted method of querying a database is to acquire a connection, create a statement from that connection, and then execute a query from that statement.

```
// load driver
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(..);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT..");
// ...
```

However, I am unsure of how to treat a second query to the same database.

1. Can another query be executed safely on the same `Statement` object, or must another statement be created from the `Connection` object in order to execute another query?
2. If the same `Statement` object can be used for multiple queries, what is the purpose of the `Statement` class (since it would then make more sense for a `Connection.executeQuery()` method to exist)?

Comment: For the first part, did you try doing that yourself? Did you get any exceptions or any unwanted output?

Comment: There are tons of examples in the web. You could watch them over there, try yourself and if you get exception or troubles improve your question, so we could help you more precise.

Comment: @RohitJain I have not, but I'm near-certain that several queries can be executed from the same Statement option, which leads me to wonder if there's any drawbacks or safety concerns with doing so (question 1), and as a result, what the point of the Statement class is (question 2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can reuse the `Statement` object, but the `ResultSet` objects returned by the `executeQuery` closes already opened resultsets.

See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) for the explanation

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.

So the following occurs:

```
// load driver
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(..);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("select ..");
// do something with result ... or not
ResultSet result2 = stmt.executeQuery("select ...");
// result is now closed, you cannot read from it anymore
// do something with result2
stmt.close(); // will close the resultset bound to it
```

For example you can find an open source implementation of Statement in the jTDS project.
In the [Statement.executeQuery() method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.2/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/JtdsPreparedStatement.java#JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery%28%29) you can see a call to [`initialize()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.2/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/JtdsStatement.java#JtdsStatement.initialize%28%29) that [closes all the resultsets](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.2/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/JtdsStatement.java#JtdsStatement.closeAllResultSets%28%29) already opened

```
protected void initialize() throws SQLException {
    updateCount = -1;
    resultQueue.clear();
    genKeyResultSet = null;
    tds.clearResponseQueue();
    // FIXME Should old exceptions found now be thrown instead of lost?
    messages.exceptions = null;
    messages.clearWarnings();
    closeAllResultSets();
}
```

Comment: If all execution methods implicitly close a statement's current ResultSet (if open), is it necessary to explicitly close a ResultSet before executing another query?

Comment: @Vulcan you are right, as you noticed and as it is said in the javadoc, the `execute*()` methods on a `Statement` seems to close any open `ResultSet` that derives from it, so in practice it is not mandatory to call `close()` on it before issuing a new execute, but it is good practice to close resources that you have opened.

Comment: See my edit for the jTDS open source implementation as an example.

Comment: Thanks.  Marking this answer as accepted because I feel it most accurately answered the original question, although I also appreciate the answers of others, as every single one taught me something new.

Answer (score 4):

Programmatically, you can reuse the same connection and the same statement for more than one query and close the statement and the connection at the end.

However, this is not a good practice. Application performance is very sensitive to the way database is accessed. Ideally, each connection should be open for the least amount of time possible. Then, the connections must be pooled. Going by that, you would enclose each query in a block of `{open connection, create a prepared statement, run query, close statement, close connection}`. This is also the way most SQL Templates are implemented. If concurrency permits, you can fire several such queries at the same time using a thread pool.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but what is the reasoning behind keeping a connection open for the least amount of time possible?  Is it better to keep one connection open to handle 10 queries per minute, or open a new connection an average of once every 6 seconds?

Comment: @Vulcan Its not the same. You have the connection open the least time and then you return it back to the pool. The pool will keep the connection open for you. Because you "close" the connection every time you are sure that its always returned to the pool. If you handle it yourself, then the risks increases that you miss the close and run into database sessions or memory leek problems.

Answer (score 2):

I have one thing to add should you use Connection and Statement in a threaded environment.
My experience shows that stmt.executeQuery(..) is save to use in a parallel environment but with the consequence that each query is serialized and thus processed sequencially, not yielding any speed-ups.
So it es better to use a new Connection (not Statement) for every thread.

For a standard sequential environment my experience has shown that reusing Statements is no problem at all and ResultSets need not be closed manually.

Comment: I found this extremely helpful, as I *am* using Connection and Statement in a threaded environment.  Combined with what *Udo Held*'s answer advises, I feel like I've learned what I need to for multi-threaded database connections.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's why we have the concept of classes in object oriented programming . A class defines constituent members which enable its instances to have state and behavior. Here statement deals with everything related to an sql statement. There are so many more function that one might perform like batch queries etc.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it's one statement for one query. It might not be necessary to do that but when writing real application, you don't want to repeat those same steps again and again. That's against the DRY principal, plus it also will get more complicated as the application grows.

It's good to write objects that will handle that kind of low level (repetitive) stuffs, and provide different methods to access db by providing the queries.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about creating new statements. However opening up a database connection may be resource intensive and opening and closing connections does impact performance.

Leaving up connections in some self management way usually is pretty bad.

You should consider using [connection pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool). You usually issue a close commando however you are only giving that connection back to the pool. When you request a new connection then it will reuse the connection you gave back earlier.

You may want to have different statements for one connection. Statement is an implementation and an interface. Depending on what you need you sometimes want a use a [CallableStatment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html). Some some logic may be reused when required.

Comment: Thanks, I'd never encountered connection pooling before, and it seems like an extremely useful concept that I'll be using in my server application.

Comment: @Vulcan If server application is a web application then the application server can do the connection pooling. The configuration should be decribed in your application server. Otherwise you could use http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/ or some other toolset of your choice.

Comment: My apologies, I don't believe I was clear with that statement; it's simply a Java application hosting a server socket for client sockets to connect to.